# Making only a part of model field available in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have a such model:

```
GENDER_CHOICES = ( ('M', 'Male'), ('F', 'Female') )
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)

class FrontPage(models.Model):
    female = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name="female")
    male = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name="male")
```

Once I attempt to add a new FrontPage object via the Admin page, I can select "Female" profiles for the male field of FrontPage, how can I restrict that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ForeignKey`'s [`limit_choices_to`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to) argument will allow you to limit the choices available via the admin interface.